# Java date parser off by two years

Tags: java, date

I really don't know where to start debugging this one.

Code:

```
String date = "Mon, 15 Oct 2012 20:32:12 +0000 (GMT)";

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:MM:ss Z");

        try {
            Date date2 = format.parse(date);
            System.err.println("parsed: " + date2);
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to parse: " + format);
        }
```

Output:

```
parsed: Fri Aug 15 16:00:12 EDT 2014
```

Why is this off by two years and two months?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use small `mm` for minutes

```
EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z
```

Comment: @djechlin: It simply added 32 months to your date.

Answer (score 4):

Jigar Joshi has already answered the main question - but just a tip that setting `DateFormat.setLenient(false)` (see the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29)) will avoid a lot of parsing problems like this, because the format won't silently accept nonsensical values.

A second tip (because this bit me recently) is to always test your DateFormats with both a.m. and p.m. timestamps, because it is easy to mix up `hh` and `HH` formats (12-hour and 24-hour format). Otherwise, you can find that your test data works fine, but real data fails with confusing errors.

Comment: Thanks.  Very useful and obviously reflects what was going through my head anyway.